# How do I get the return value from a process run by subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to assign the return value of `python --version` to a variable using the code below.:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import subprocess
os.system('pwd')
print ("check the version of python")
output = subprocess.Popen(["python --version"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(ver, error)= output.communicate()
print "python is:",ver
```

The output I'm getting is :

```
/home/mobaxterm/Desktop/mypy
check the version of python
Python 2.7.10
python is:
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know you can get it via `sys.version_info`, right?

Comment: also select the tick mark near to the answer that gave you a desired output. this is how you should accept an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python writes its version information to `stderr` (variable `error`, in your code) - like most other products.

Nothing was written to `stdout`.  You will notice that the variable `ver` **was** printed, it was an empty string.

You also failed to direct `stderr`:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["python --version"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
             stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: Because you did not direct stderr to PIPE

Comment: modified the code as output = subprocess.Popen(["python --version"],stderr= subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(ver,error)= output.communicate()
print "python is:",error   and got the desired output.

Comment: Please note the comment made by @johnrsharpe

Comment: @johnrsharpe actually my intent is to check the version of python and if not correct want to install the desired version.

Comment: @cdarke  thanks much for your inputs; it worked for me when i printed the error value.